# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Your InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream

Tags: java, xls, xssf, poi-hssf

When I'm reading Excel file(.xls format), I keep getting an Exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Your Input Stream was neither an OLE 2 stream, nor an OOXML stream.
```

I Go-ogled and found that if the input stream is not supporting reset or mark, I should wrap it with `pushbackStream`. My input stream is not mark\reset supported.

So using `pushbackStream` is the only option? How to use it? And whats the use of it?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure your file really is an Excel .xls file? And not, say, a .csv or .html file with the extension changed?

Comment: No, its a Excel .xls file.

Comment: Please provide your SSCCE.

Comment: The file may be empty as well, like reading from the InputStream failed or all data was already previously read

Answer (score 6):

```
Your InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Your InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream
```

I guess you are using Workbook Factory OR a different format input file and different workbook type. This error usually pops up when its not able to not able to read the file type. Apache POI does not check the file extension. If you open it in a text editor, you'll see that instead it'll be in a different format. Or you might be initializing the workbook type to HSSF or XSSF, before using Workbook Factory.

Simpler solution is to open the file using Microsoft Excel and save it as another file(using **File>Save** As option from Microsoft **Excel > Menu**).

Workbook Factory does not check the file extension, Instead it checks the file MIME type. Basically excel works with different files(Eg: the files created using third party applications, excel 2003 version), but Apache POI is very specific.

`PushbackInputStream` adds "push back" or "unread" functionality to another input stream. It allows you to read ahead a few bytes to see what is coming, before you can determine how to interpret the current byte.

If you are not using Workbook Factory, `PushbackInputStream` is the only alternative I guess.

If you can share the code here I can test it and reconfirm it.

Comment: Your suggestion don't help me :(

Comment: I can help you if you can tell me about the error in detail.

Comment: Thank you, But I don't remember the problem. I have solved it! :)

Comment: CAN you provide solution @Andrey E

Comment: @Labeo sadly I don't remember that problem and how I solved it. Think You should create a separate question if this answer didn't help you.
Or just explain your problem in detail and share some code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33175608/unable-to-read-excel-files-in-java-getting-2-below-error-in-java